# Show repeated tasks in org-agenda grid?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, time-date

Is there any way to get repeated tasks to appear in org-agenda grid? Right now they are always shown at the bottom.

In this example the tasks was scheduled to repeat every day **at 12:00**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it simply repeats, put the repeater in the timestamp, but don't mark it as scheduled.

The SCHEDULED "property" (in quotes because it's technically not quite an org mode property) is specifically for tasks and projects that must be started at that date, and as such they're displayed separately.

Comment: Yes, `SCHEDULED:` was added automatically by org-schedule command. Wow, you are amazing!  Do you know by any chance if this could also work for hourly entries? That is, could you make `<2023-07-29 Sat 12:00 +2h>` task reappear on the same day (at 14:00, 16:00, 18:00 ...) multiple times? I'd honestly never thought about that. It works! Removing it made daily entry appear in the grid.

Comment: Yeah, don't use `org-schedule`, just add a timestamp with `C-c .` or `org-time-stamp` if you have other keybindings. And.. I'm not that amazing, I just read the org-mode manual a dozen times while working on my GTD package. And, I don't see why that wouldn't work for hourly entries; they're just a timestamp with a repeater, right?

Comment: `timestamp with a repeater` yes, exactly. I've checked `org-agenda-custom-commands` and there are no "ignore-schedule"-like entries. Still hourly entries don't repeat within the same day - they do reappear on subsequent days (as single entries) and org-wild-notifier picks them up correctly (after applying [the patch](https://github.com/akhramov/org-wild-notifier.el/issues/41)). It's not a big deal (it's easier to remember a task within the same day than within multiple days), but it's strange if it's working for you.

Comment: `I just read the org-mode manual a dozen times` for me that's definitely amazing, emacs manual is one of the most convoluted books I've ever tried to read.

Comment: Well, if that doesn't work, then that's another question :) I haven't tried it on my side, I haven't had a need to.

Comment: Also emacs and org-mode have different manuals; and emacs' manual may seem obtuse but it does present the information in a logical way for learning purposes. It's just not clear because there's so much foundational information to learn, kinda like learning music theory.

Comment: Thanks, I will repost it then. One more thing that may worth noting here (it may be obvious though) is that if you stop using org-schedule (that adds SCHEDULE: "property") make sure that the active timestamp is placed below `:PROPERTIES:` drawer. I initially forgot about it and I think that it invalidated `:PROPERTIES:` (org-wild-notifier stopped working for example).

Comment: Correct; you can check org's syntax to  see what it expects: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-syntax.html